# execute vsto file after instalation - Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have developing a setup project to install a addin in outlook.
What i want to do is, in the installer have a dialog with two radiobuttons, so the user can choose if wants to install the vsto file.

I know how to add the dialog, but how can i do the rest?

regards

Comment: What do you mean with "vsto file"? Do you mean the VSTO runtime?

Comment: is the VSTO Deployment Manifest (.vsto), to install the definitions in outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis,

First of all I, would suggest not writing your installer in C#. All the non-free versions of Visual Studio allow for you to edit Microsoft Setup Projects and there is also [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) and the [Nullsoft Scriptable Installer System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

However, if you insist on going down this path, the class [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z2ck8eh.aspx) has a static member called [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx).

Comment: yes i am using the microsoft setup project. and i want to do that in microsoft setup project,

Comment: Ok perhaps you should edit your question to clarify. I don't have Visual Studio on this machine so I can't figure it out.